# Получение ссылки на новое видео youtube

Tags: python, youtube-api

Я пишу код, в котором частью является функция рассылки уведомлений о новых видео YouTube (а также трансляциях, shorts) какого-то канала. Мне нужны просто ссылка и название, ничего другого. Я могу реализовать это с помощью обычного bs4, но я сомневаюсь, что это оптимальное решение. Я уверен, что это следует делать с помощью YouTube API, но сам я в нём, увы, разобраться не могу.

Comment: Youtube [рассылает уведомления о новом контенте через PubSub хаб](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications). Для получения уведомлений вам нужно поднять сервер и [подписать](https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscribe) URL `https://your_server/some/path` на обновления нужных вам каналов. Хаб будет постить уведомления как POST запросы по адресу `https://your_server/some/path`. От вас требуется только обрабатывать эти POST-ы и пересылать уведомления дальше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Под вашу задачу хорошо подойдет библиотека [**`yt-dlp`**](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp)

**Установка такая:**

```py
pip install yt-dlp
```

---

После установки библиотеку можно использовать прямо из консольного интерфейса.

Формат:

```py
yt-dlp --arg-1 --arg-2 --arg-3 value <ссылка на канал/плейлист/видео>
```

Например:

```py
yt-dlp --skip-download --print-json --flat-playlist https://www.youtube.com/@MrBeast/videos
```

После выполнения данной команды, запущенный процесс вернет вам краткую информацию о каждом видео на канале. Там есть и название и ссылка.

Все параметры, конечно, перечислять не буду, их там очень много, описание каждого можете посмотреть в [**README.md**](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) в репозитории на GitHub.

---

Ну и конечно, можно использовать как библиотеку для Python:

```py
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL


options = {
    'extract_flat': True
}

def get_channel_videos(channel_url: str) -> list[dict[str, str]]:
    with YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
        channel_data = ydl.extract_info(channel_url, download=False)
        
        return [
            {'title': video.get('title'), 'url': video.get('url')}
            for video in channel_data['entries']
        ]

for video in get_channel_videos('https://www.youtube.com/@MrBeast/videos'):
    print(video['title'], video['url'])
```

Опять же, формат вывода у метода `extract_info` — это очень большой и сложный `json` — он же `dict` в Python.

На первый раз, для более детального анализа рекомендую выгрузить результат выполнения метода в какой-нибудь файл и вручную изучить что интересного можно узнать о видео.

---

Конкретно по вашей задаче — имеет смысл добавить аргумент `playlistend`, который ограничивает количество получаемых видео до 10 штук, чтобы не выгружать весь канал:

```py
options = {
    'extract_flat': True,
    'playlistend': 10
}
```

И затем, сравнивая со старым списком, можно посмотреть какие видео были добавлены на канал

Comment: А есть ли вариант не проверять раз в какое-то время список роликов, а именно получать уведомления о новых видео?

Comment: Возможно есть, я о таком не знаю ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Кажется, на ютьюбе можно выложить видео с доступом по ссылке, но при этом разослать нотификацию подписчикам. Полагаю, что для такой ситуации этот код не сработает.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, и вправду. Подумаю на днях как еще можно сделать :)

Answer (score 1):

С помощью обычного bs4 это будет и проще, поскольку вы его понимаете(на сколько я понял), и, возможно, оптимальнее по времени, ведь Вы умеете с ним работать.

Я бы на Вашем месте сделал именно так.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).